# Из одного проекта получить доступ к другому

Tags: gtest, visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте.

Есть решение (`solution`), в котором находятся два проекта: `LexicalAnalyzer`, в котором определен класс `Analyzer`, и `LexicalAnalyzerTest`, в котором я провожу тестирование класса `Analyzer`.

Так вот, как мне во втором проекте создать объект класса `Analyzer`? Вроде в `Project -> LexicalAnalyzerTest Properties -> References` добавил ссылку на первый проект.

Comment: Заинклудил .hpp и .cpp, вроде заработало, вот только правильно ли это?

Comment: .cpp не нужно инклудить, это неправильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В References не нужно добавлять. References это для managed-assemblies, вашему проекту на native C++ это никак не поможет.

1. Добавьте в тестовый проект в разделе Compiler -> Additional include directories путь к папкам, где лежат заголовочные файлы вашего класса из основного проекта.
2. Во вкладке linker в проперти Input добавьте полный путь к объектнику тестируемого класса, но это не самое лучшее решение. Лучше вынесите ваш тестируемый класс в отдельный проект, статическую либу, и линкуйтесь уже к ней.